# Read-only file system after downloading files

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, read-only

My ubuntu became `Read-only` when my hard drive works a lot! For example after downloading big files(more than 1GB) or `full-upgrading` with apt(about 400MB) i cant open any desktop app or even use `tab-completion` in terminal! The solution is to restart laptop and when `initramfs` page appears run this command:

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda7 
(and press "a" to answer "inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found")
```

Where `/dev/sda7` is my `/home` partition and i downloaded files into this partition.

After run this command my ubutnu boots again but when hard drive works a lot the problem came back! Whats the problem? Is it my hard-drive problem or just a software problem? How can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

Additional information:

- asus x450ld
- ubuntu 18.04
- KDE desktop

---

output of `df -i` command:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             998575    581   997994    1% /dev
tmpfs           1006147    981  1005166    1% /run
/dev/sda6       6566400 858571  5707829   14% /
tmpfs           1006147    136  1006011    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1006147      6  1006141    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1006147     18  1006129    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        12860  12860        0  100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop1        12847  12847        0  100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop2          370    370        0  100% /snap/pdftk/1
/dev/loop3          370    370        0  100% /snap/pdftk/9
/dev/loop4        12842  12842        0  100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/sda7      40853504 541797 40311707    2% /home
tmpfs           1006147     41  1006106    1% /run/user/1000
```

---

output of `journalctl /dev/sda`

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-07-11 04:11:38 +0430, end at Fri 2018-09-28 20:48:21 +0330. --
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:9c03] type 00 class 0x010601
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [io  0xf0b0-0xf0b7]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x14: [io  0xf0a0-0xf0a3]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x18: [io  0xf090-0xf097]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x1c: [io  0xf080-0xf083]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x20: [io  0xf060-0xf07f]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf7a22000-0xf7a227ff]
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq stag pm led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: scsi host0: ahci
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 2J   PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
september 28 02:28:38 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
september 28 13:22:40 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
september 28 13:22:40 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
september 28 13:22:40 X450LD kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
```

Comment: I suspect a failing hard drive: apparently, you file system regularly is being corrupted. If this is a desktop, check for dust inside the system and check the connections.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks, I don't think it's connections problem because my distro works well about 3 months (i didn't download any big file) but 3 months ago i saw this problem after downloading big files and today after downloading big files again :(

Comment: How old is the drive?

Comment: @EduardoLópez about 4 years!

Comment: Can you post the output of "df -i"?

Comment: @EduardoLópez sure. question updated :)

Comment: `journalctl /dev/sda` will show you what the system logs about your (probably) failing drive. Backup. Backup. BACKUP!

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. I don't understand result of this command, so updated my question with output of this command :)

Comment: Read `man smartctl`, and use `smartctl` to look at stats the drive keeps.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I'd spare me the troubleshooting and get a new drive. Maybe use that one for additional storage, but you usually want to avoid using failing drives like the pest....